# How to subtract date/time values from different rows in the same column in sas

Tags: sas, calculated-columns, subtraction

I got this values in my table and I need to know how can I subtract them creating another column with the results.

```
19FEB2018:14:24:43.00
23MAR2018:12:57:58.00
28MAR2018:15:37:37.00
29JUN2018:10:30:33.00
29JUN2018:13:43:07.00
```

What I need is:

```
1- 0h
2- (23MAR2018:12:57:58.00 - 19FEB2018:14:24:43.00)
3- (...)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the DIF() function.

```
data have;
 input dt datetime.;
 format dt datetime22.2 ;
cards;
19FEB2018:14:24:43.00
23MAR2018:12:57:58.00
28MAR2018:15:37:37.00
29JUN2018:10:30:33.00
29JUN2018:13:43:07.00
;

data want;
  set have ;
  diff = dif(dt);
  format diff hhmm12.2 ;
run;
```

[image]